# How to prove in a topological vector space in R^n: cl(A) + cl(B) =cl(clA+clB), where cl denotes closure and A, B compact convex sets?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let A,B be compact convex sets, then Is equal to cl(A+B)=cl(cl(A)+cl(B))? why? Thank you.

Comment: What have you done for this? A compact set is closed - you probably know that. What about the sum of two compact sets, do you know something about this?